# Is a StartCoroutine needed for a call from inside one co-routine to another co-routine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

When you have nested co-routines like

```
void Update()
{
    if(someTest)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Foo());
    }
}

IEnumerator Foo()
{
    doStuff = true;
    yield return StartCoroutine(Bar());
    doStuff = false;
}

IEnumerator Bar()
{
    //Very important things!
}
```

Is the `StartCoroutine` in `yield return StartCoroutine(Bar());` necessary?

Are we allowed to just do

```
void Update()
{
    if(someTest)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Foo());
    }
}

IEnumerator Foo()
{
    doStuff = true;
    yield return Bar();
    doStuff = false;
}

IEnumerator Bar()
{
    //Very important things!
}
```

If we are allowed, does this have any impact on the program behavior/performance?

Comment: Based on the latest answer to this question (and some short testing) they result in the same: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/724244/yield-return-m-vs-yield-return-startcoroutine.html

Comment: If you want to quote andymilsom's answer and post it here I would accept it.

Comment: They are not the-same as that answer says. I will put an answer to address the differences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the StartCoroutine in yield return StartCoroutine(Bar());
>   necessary?

*No*, you are allowed to use `yield return Bar();`.

> If we are allowed, does this have any impact on the program
>   behavior/performance?

*Yes* to both behavior and performance question.

**The Difference**:

---

**`yield return StartCoroutine(coroutineFunction())`:**

- Inner coroutine(`Bar`) will be started *before* yielding
- *Memory Allocation*: 56 bytes
- *Calls*: 2
- When a parent coroutine is killed, the child coroutine that is
  started with `StartCoroutine` continues to run.

---

**`yield return coroutineFunction()`:**

- Inner coroutine(`Bar`) will be started *after* yielding
- *Memory Allocation*: 32 bytes
- *Calls*: 3
- When a parent coroutine is killed, the child coroutine that is
  started with `yield return coroutineFunction()` is killed as well.
  This is every important to know especially when you need to stop a
  parent coroutine with its children.
- *Faster*:

  Probably because it allocates less memory. When used in a `for` loop
  it is faster than `yield return StartCoroutine(coroutineFunction())`.
  This is even true even though it has more calls. Also, *Time* and
  *Self ms* from the Profiler shows that its values are less than the ones from `yield return StartCoroutine(coroutineFunction())`.

**In conclusion**:

The `yielding` difference is almost like the `i++` vs `++i` (post and pre increment). If you care about memory management then go with the second method `yield return coroutineFunction()` as it allocates less memory. Also if you want to be able to stop all the inner or child coroutines when the parent one is stopped then also use `yield return coroutineFunction()`.

Comment: Thanks, Very informative. Programmer do you work for Unity or just very knowledgeable, I see your name a lot on Unity questions. Also where did you get the numbers for calls and memory allocations, do you have a reference I could read more from or did you just profile both test cases and got the numbers from that?

Comment: I don't work for Unity. I just use Unity everyday and always study its internal stuff with .NET Reflector. [This](http://pastebin.com/4CNw260z) is my test1 script which allocates more memory. [This](http://pastebin.com/dV4JNdB1) is my test2 script that allocates less memory. Go to Window->Profiler. You will be able to see these information. I just spend about an hour to verify this information again since it has been long since I did this experiment. The information is still valid with the latest Unity version.