# IEnumerator yield return

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

```
private IEnumerator SpawnAllWaves()
{
    for(int waveIndex = startingWave; waveIndex < waveConfigs.Count; waveIndex++)
    {
        var currentWave = waveConfigs[waveIndex];
        yield return StartCoroutine(SpawnAllEnemiesInWave(currentWave));
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
}
```

Hello friends, we used yield return in two different ways. What is the difference between them?
It would be nice if you can help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a StartCoroutine needed for a call from inside one co-routine to another co-routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729845/1092820)

Comment: I think I understand, thanks